# Display 0 for kendo.toString

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui

I have a kendoGrid in my application. And my problem is:
I have a 0 in my database but when I use kendo.tostring in template for kendoGrid he don't display the 0. But when I have 0,2 the kendo.tostring display 0,2. So how can I succeed to display only 0 ??

This is mys javascript code:

```js
$("#tab_intensite").kendoGrid({
    dataSource: intensite_data,
    scrollable: true,
    sortable: true,
    pageable: false,
    detailInit: function(e) {
        $("<div/>").appendTo(e.detailCell).kendoGrid({
            dataSource: {
                data: intensite,
                filter: {
                    field: "idDepart",
                    operator: "eq",
                    value: e.data.idDepart
                }
            },
            columns: [{
                field: "intituledep",
                title: "D&EacuteSIGNATION"
            }]
        });
    },
    editable: true,
    height: 400,
    change: function() {
        console.log($this);
        $this.attr("font-weight", "bold");
    },
    save: function() {
        $("#tableau_saisie_intensite").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.update;
        $("#tableau_saisie_intensite").data("kendoGrid").refresh();
        $("#tableau_saisie_intensite").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.bind("change", function(e) {
            setdatasourcessss();
        });
    },
    columns: [{
        field: "cel",
        title: "D&Eacute;PART",
        width: 50,
        headerAttributes: {
            style: "text-align: center;"
        }
    }, {
        field: "date_releve",
        title: "Date Relev&eacute;",
        width: 50,
        format: "{0:dd/MM/yyyy }",
        attributes: {
            style: "text-align: center;"
        },
        headerAttributes: {
            style: "text-align: center;"
        },
        footerTemplate: "<div id='date_intensite_total' style='width:98%;position:relative;text-align: center;'  ></div> "
    }, {
        field: "n",
        title: "N",
        width: 50,
        attributes: {
            style: "text-align: center;"
        },
        footerTemplate: "#= kendo.toString(sum, 'n') # A",
        template: "#= (n) ? kendo.toString(n)+ ' A': ''# <span style='float: right;' class='k-icon k-edit'></span>",
        headerAttributes: {
            style: "text-align: center;"
        }
    }, {
        field: "ph1",
        title: "PH1",
        width: 50,
        attributes: {
            style: "text-align: center;"
        },
        footerTemplate: "#= kendo.toString(sum, 'n') # A",
        template: "#= (ph1) ? kendo.toString(ph1, 'n')+ ' A': ''# <span style='float: right;' class='k-icon k-edit'></span>",
        headerAttributes: {
            style: "text-align: center;"
        }
    }, {
        field: "ph2",
        title: "PH2",
        width: 50,
        attributes: {
            style: "text-align: center;"
        },
        footerTemplate: "#= kendo.toString(sum, 'n') # A",
        template: "#=(ph2) ?kendo.toString(ph2)+ ' A': ''# <span style='float: right;' class='k-icon k-edit'></span> ",
        headerAttributes: {
            style: "text-align: center;"
        }
    }, {
        field: "ph3",
        title: "PH3",
        width: 50,
        attributes: {
            style: "text-align: center;"
        },
        footerTemplate: "#= kendo.toString(sum, 'n') # A",
        template: "#=(ph3) ?kendo.toString(ph3, 'n')+ ' A' : ''# <span style='float: right;' class='k-icon k-edit'></span>",
        headerAttributes: {
            style: "text-align: center;"
        }
    }],
});
```

If someone can help me it will be great ! Thank in advance !!

Comment: You may want to use such as `(n == null) ? '' : kendo.toString(n)+ ' A'`

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any problem with the `kendo.toString()` statements in your code. However there is one problem located on the ternary operation, on `template` field.

```js
template: (n) ? kendo.toString(n) + ' A' : ''
```

With that ternary statement, whenever `n` is `0`, then it returns `''` because `0` is **falsey** value. Try to change `''` into `'0'` then your problem will be gone.

You need to apply the changes to `template` fields for columns `n`, `ph1`, `ph2`, and `ph3`.

```js
columns: [
    ....
    {
        field: "n",
        template: "#= (n) ? kendo.toString(n)+ ' A': '0'# <span style='float: right;' class='k-icon k-edit'></span>",
        ...
    },
    {
        field: "ph1",
        template: "#= (ph1) ? kendo.toString(ph1, 'n')+ ' A': '0'# <span style='float: right;' class='k-icon k-edit'></span>",
        ...
    },
    {
        field: "ph2",
        template: "#=(ph2) ?kendo.toString(ph2)+ ' A': '0'# <span style='float: right;' class='k-icon k-edit'></span> ",
        ...
    },
    {
        field: "ph3",
        template: "#=(ph3) ?kendo.toString(ph3, 'n')+ ' A' : '0'# <span style='float: right;' class='k-icon k-edit'></span>",
        ...
    },
],
```

The snipped below contains the complete fixes, you can run it to see the result.

```js
var data = [{
    "cel": "a",
    "date_releve": "a",
    "n": 0.2,
    "ph1": 0,
    "ph3": 0.2,
    "ph2": 0.5
}]

$("#grid").kendoGrid({
    dataSource: data,
    scrollable: true,
    sortable: true,
    pageable: false,
    detailInit: function(e) {
        $("<div/>").appendTo(e.detailCell).kendoGrid({
            dataSource: {
                data: intensite,
                filter: {
                    field: "idDepart",
                    operator: "eq",
                    value: e.data.idDepart
                }
            },
            columns: [{
                field: "intituledep",
                title: "D&EacuteSIGNATION"
            }]
        });
    },
    editable: true,
    height: 400,
    change: function() {
        console.log($this);
        $this.attr("font-weight", "bold");
    },
    save: function() {
        $("#tableau_saisie_intensite").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.update;
        $("#tableau_saisie_intensite").data("kendoGrid").refresh();
        $("#tableau_saisie_intensite").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.bind("change", function(e) {
            setdatasourcessss();
        });
    },
    columns: [{
        field: "cel",
        title: "D&Eacute;PART",
        width: 50,
        headerAttributes: {
            style: "text-align: center;"
        }
    }, {
        field: "date_releve",
        title: "Date Relev&eacute;",
        width: 50,
        format: "{0:dd/MM/yyyy }",
        attributes: {
            style: "text-align: center;"
        },
        headerAttributes: {
            style: "text-align: center;"
        },
        footerTemplate: "<div id='date_intensite_total' style='width:98%;position:relative;text-align: center;'  ></div> "
    }, {
        field: "n",
        title: "N",
        width: 50,
        attributes: {
            style: "text-align: center;"
        },
        footerTemplate: "#= kendo.toString(sum, 'n') # A",
        template: "#= (n) ? kendo.toString(n)+ ' A': '0'# <span style='float: right;' class='k-icon k-edit'></span>",
        headerAttributes: {
            style: "text-align: center;"
        }
    }, {
        field: "ph1",
        title: "PH1",
        width: 50,
        attributes: {
            style: "text-align: center;"
        },
        footerTemplate: "#= kendo.toString(sum, 'n') # A",
        template: "#= (ph1) ? kendo.toString(ph1, 'n')+ ' A': '0'# <span style='float: right;' class='k-icon k-edit'></span>",
        headerAttributes: {
            style: "text-align: center;"
        }
    }, {
        field: "ph2",
        title: "PH2",
        width: 50,
        attributes: {
            style: "text-align: center;"
        },
        footerTemplate: "#= kendo.toString(sum, 'n') # A",
        template: "#=(ph2) ?kendo.toString(ph2)+ ' A': '0'# <span style='float: right;' class='k-icon k-edit'></span> ",
        headerAttributes: {
            style: "text-align: center;"
        }
    }, {
        field: "ph3",
        title: "PH3",
        width: 50,
        attributes: {
            style: "text-align: center;"
        },
        footerTemplate: "#= kendo.toString(sum, 'n') # A",
        template: "#=(ph3) ?kendo.toString(ph3, 'n')+ ' A' : '0'# <span style='float: right;' class='k-icon k-edit'></span>",
        headerAttributes: {
            style: "text-align: center;"
        }
    }],
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.1.221/styles/kendo.common.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.1.221/styles/kendo.rtl.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.1.221/styles/kendo.default.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.1.221/styles/kendo.mobile.all.min.css">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.1.221/js/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.1.221/js/jszip.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.1.221/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>

<div id="grid"></div>
```

Comment: Yes thank you !! I saw my code was wrong ! But I have an other question. If I want to hide the 0 how can I do this ? I want to know if in kendo.tostring it's possible to display all number but not 0 in my case.
By exemple I have a date and I want to display all the number includng the 0 but if I have no date I juste want to display the number and not the 0. I hope it's clear

Comment: I don't think `kendo.toString` have such capability. you should be able use something like this `n ? '' : kendo.toString(n)`. if `n` is `0`, then empty string will be returned